# Use jQuery to add break into header that's too long

Tags: javascript, jquery, string

Using jquery, I want to go through all of the h3 tags inside of one parent div. There can be 1 or many. I have to check each header to make sure it's not more than 35 characters w/ spaces. If they are, I have to put a `<br>` after the 35th character (also 70th, 105th, etc).

It's a quick and dirty fix until we make permanent changes to the script that's making the headers. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: can you try `$.each` and `str_len` of headers ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use CSS instead, and use 35ex for 35 characters.

http://jsfiddle.net/EPft9/

```
div.parent h3 {
    max-width: 35ex; //Which should give you 35 characters.
}
```

Comment: `"Supercalif ragilist".length` is 19. Also Could you check http://jsfiddle.net/EPft9/1/

Comment: Doesn't look like you counted the whitespace after "ragilist " ;)

Comment: It is an interesting approach though, as my first thought was to do `substr`. +1

Comment: Ahh.. it is the whitespace.. my bad.

Answer (score 1):

**Approach 1:** (Without substring)

You can wrap a div inside each header and force div width to wrap using css.

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/2c4J6/2/

**JS:**

```
$('h3').wrapInner('<div class="limitHeader" />');
```

**CSS:**

```
.limitHeader {
    width: 360px; /* Update as your font-style*/
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

**Approach 2:** (using substring)

The approach 1 may not be reliable as the width of each character is different. So if you really want it to have exact 35 character then try a simple iterate like below,

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/2c4J6/

```
$('h3').html(function(idx, v) {
    if (v.length > 35) {
        var result = '';
        for (var i = 0; i < (v.length / 35); i++) {
           result += v.substr(35*i, 35) + '<br/>';
        }
        return result;
    }
    return v;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The better solution is to use plain Javascript:

```
function fixHeader(el) {
var elements = el.getElementsBYTagName("h3");

    for (x in elements) {
        fixHtml(elements[x]);
    }
}

function fixHtml(el) {
var html = "",
    j = 0;

    for (var i = 0; i < el.innerHTML.length; i++) {
        html += el.innerHTML[i];

        if (j > 35) {
            html += "<br />";
            j = 0;
        }

        j++;
    }
}
```

You can use this function by calling fixHeader(yourElement).

A way better solution would be CSS of course.. You can just create an inner element with a width.

```
<div>
    <div style="width:100px;">My superduper long text which is absolutely to long and definitly needs breaks.</div>
</div>
```

You can adjust the number of characters by increasing the width.

If you really like to use jQuery... :

```
$(el).find("h3").each(function() {
    var html = $(this).html(),
    j = 0,
    new_html = "";

    for (var i = 0; i < html.length; i++) {
        new_html += html[i];

        if (j > 35) {
            new_html += html[i];
            j = 0;
        }

        j++;
    }

    $(this).html(new_html);
});
```